# cutting a wav file into segments

Tags: java, c++, c, wav

I want to write a simple program that takes a moderately sized wav file (60 seconds or so) and cuts it into 1 second length segments of the same format (1.wav,2.wav,... etc) ... Is there a simple C++ or java library that could do this? I don't want to have to manipulate header information

Comment: If you don't want to manipulate the header info, then the spitted chunks will not be playable.

Comment: Maybe a perl/python/shell script can do that easily.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the tcl Snack library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [libsndfile](http://mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/). Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814531/absolute-beginners-guide-to-working-with-audio-in-c-c) other post.
You will want to:

- remove the WAV headers to access the raw [PCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) sample data
- loop through `sample_rate` samples which will represent 1 second of audio and package these buffers into a new WAV file (with headers) until you reach `EOF` of the original.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Shell script wrapped around the `ffmpeg` command line utility. Also, `sox`.

http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can use AudioInputStream class to do it. Also check [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.java) site for more info about AudioInputStream

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg has two flags that might be of us: -t which sets the duration of the target file, and -ss which sets the point at which you start reading in the input file.

So:

ffmpeg -t 2 -i input.mp3 output.mp3
ffmpeg -ss 2 -t 2 -i input.mp3 output2.mp3

Creates two files - one which contains the first two seconds of input.mp3, and one which contains two seconds of input.mp3 starting from the 2 seconds in (i.e. the second two seconds...).

Combinations of this can probably be achieved to get what you want from the file.